# Advanced WiFi Analyzer

Tags: windows-10, wifi

I'm looking for an advanced WiFi analyzer, preferably for Windows because the most-portable device I have is a Windows tablet.

Things I'd like it to do:

- Analyze the devices it hears on a channel & show their mode (802.11n, ac, etc), bandwidth (20 MHz? 40 MHz?), TX Rate (800 Mbps? 1300 Mbps?), etc
- Show how often each device has to re-transmit packets (i.e. Device A rarely re-transmits, but Device B re-transmits 80% of its packets and has to drop its TX Rate as a result)
- Let me select another WiFi adapter (the built-in adapter doesn't support Monitor Mode, but my USB interface does, so please use that one)